# NHibernate: How to reference the assembly of the main project from the unit test project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, reflection

I built a simple NHibernate Application but i wanted to use Mapping Attributes instead of Mapping XML.

Now i have the problem, when i create a Unit Test Project and want to load the Mapping Attributes, that my domain objects are in the other project!

This is my Unit Test:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

namespace Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
    }
}
```

In this line

```
cfg.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

I get this Exception:

```
Result Message: 
Test method Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.MappingException: The following assembly contains 
no mapped classes: Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Result StackTrace:  
at NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Assembly assembly)
   at NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Serialize(Assembly assembly)
   at Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in ...Tests\UnitTest1.cs:Line 17.
```

I guess instead of

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

I have to get somehow the assembly of my main project.

Comment: This is btw. the tutorial I used as a starting point for my unit tests: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do this was with:

`Assembly.Load("Project Name of Desired Assembly")`

I read a lot of stuff online to do this, including this post, and nothing was more simple than using this method. Also, the methods mentioned by JoelC probably work, however I couldn't get them to work for me and this worked no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, calling `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` from unit tests usually will give you the unit test runner as the executing assembly.

You should be able to call `typeof([TargetAssemblyClass]).Assembly` to find your main project assembly. This, of course, requires a reference to the main project which I expect you already have.

Edit:
Calling `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof([TargetAssemblyClass]))` is another way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Is it anyhow possible to get the assembly of the whole project? because with that i have to add all Classes manually.
When i try to call `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof([Name of main project]))` i get the an error saying: 'MainProject' is a namespace but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Mike, you need to use `typeof` on a class from the main project, not your main project itself. If your main project is called `MikeSoft.Data` and you have a class within that project called `DataClient` then you want to call `typeof(MikeSoft.Data.DataClient)`.

Comment: @MiiKE To clarify further: Using the calls in my answer returns you the assembly to your entire project. If your Project is called, MikeSoft.Data and you do the call above on the DataClient class, it gives you the entire assembly. So if you call Assembly.GetTypes() it will give you a full list of all types within your project. There should be no need to call GetAssembly for each class, since that will return you the same assembly. The reason you have to use the type of a specific class is Reflection needs a point of reference to find the assembly.

Comment: ah .. got it! I tried it with one of my Domain classes, that worked, but i didnt check if i loaded only this on class into the NHibernate configuration or all in the same project! I'll check that tomorrow!